# Sybase join conversion to t-sql

Tags: sql-server

I've changed the sybase query to T-sql but for some reason I'm not able to match the result set of sybase query and T-sql after conversion. Please review my t-sql query. Any help is highly appreciated as I'm very new to sybase. Thanks

```
FROM detail 
    , hdr
    , ck
    , fd
    , master
    , subcode
    , transaction
WHERE (detail.fd_id = fd.fd_id )
    AND master.id = detail.gl_id
    AND (detail.period >= P_Start ) 
    AND (detail.period <= P_End ) 
    AND detail.version = master.version
    AND ((detail.source = @source) OR (@source IS NULL) OR @source= '' OR :@source = ' ')  
    AND detail.ct_id *= hdr.ct_id
    AND detail.inv_id *= hdr.inv_id 
    AND detail.ck_id *= ck.ck_id
    AND detail.sub *= subcode.subcode
    AND detail.tran *= transaction.transaction
    AND detail.version *= transaction.version
    AND fd.fd_group *= transaction.fd_group 
    AND ((detail._refer = @Refer) OR (ISNULL(@Refer, '') = ''))
    AND (((@IntSource = 'Z') AND ((detail.int_source = @OldVoucher) OR (ISNULL(@OldVoucher,'') = '')))
    AND (@ExcludeCB = 'N' 
        OR NOT EXISTS(SELECT * 
                      FROM version_fd_group
                      WHERE version_fd_group.version = detail.version and balancing_id = detail.id)
        )
```

===== T-SQL ===================

```
FROM detail
INNER JOIN Fd
    ON detail.fd_id = fd.fd_id
INNER JOIN master
    ON master.id = detail.gl_id AND AND (detail.period >= P_Start ) 
    AND (detail.period <= P_End ) 
    AND detail.version = master.version
    AND ((detail.source = @source) OR (@source IS NULL) OR @source= '' OR :@source = ' ') 
LEFT OUTER JOIN hdr
    ON detail.ct_id = hdr.ct_id and detail.inv_id = hdr.inv_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN ck
    ON detail.ck_id = ck.ck_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN subcode
    ON detail.gl_sub = subcode.subcode
LEFT OUTER JOIN transaction
    ON detail.tran = transaction.transaction AND detail.version = transaction.version
LEFT OUTER JOIN transaction transaction2
    ON fd.fd_group = transaction2.fd_group 
WHERE  ( (detail._refer = @Refer) OR (ISNULL(@Refer, '') = '') )
   AND (
        ( (@IntSource = 'Z') 
          AND ( (detail.int_source = @OldVoucher) OR (ISNULL(@OldVoucher,'') = '') 
        )
      )
      AND (@ExcludeCB = 'N' OR NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM version_fd_group
                     WHERE version_fd_group.version = detail.version and balancing_id = detail.id)
   )
```

Comment: Could you post what the sybase is returning and what the T-SQL is returning?

Comment: Thanks for your response, original code is very long i just posted the code where I'm little confused. Output is a report where it is generating duplicate records for same id.

Comment: Just pull a small subset of what is in Sybase that isn't in the T-SQL.

Comment: Maybe a typo here? "detail.sub *= subcode.subcode" vs "detail.gl_sub = subcode.subcode"

Comment: Why is transaction joined now twice? In Sybase version it's just once there.

Comment: Yes, james its a typo. As i understand in Sybase they used 3 left join on transaction ? detail.tran *= transaction.transaction
AND detail.version *= transaction.version
AND fd.fd_group *= transaction.fd_group

Comment: Thank you James. For identifying the error Joined twice for transaction table.

Comment: Correct terminology would help a lot: The Sybase dialect is in fact called "T-SQL". Microsoft SQL Server was originally based on Sybase and their SQL dialect is still also called "T-SQL" (T stands for "Transact" in both cases).
A more clear description would have been that that you are trying to convert the T-SQL outer join syntax to ANSI outer join syntax.

Comment: Thanks Rob for the info

Comment: The solution to this kind of issue is almost always to take the time to format the code with better line breaks and indentation to make the parentheses more readable. After doing this, the error will almost always stand out as obvious. And it will almost always have something to do with the precedence of `OR` vs `AND`.

Comment: But, it also looks like there's a typo, and we're missing a closing paren for (at least) the SQL Server version, so I can't finish doing that work for you.